# How to count tokens in dictionary values and replace each occurrence with items from a list

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop

I have a list of dictionaries something like this (x300 comments):

```
data=[{'comment': 'I nominate @Joe Smith and @Sara Jones'}, {'comment': '@Dean Gordon check out the Queen's Gambit'}]
```

I also have a list of names like this (x2000 names):

```
names=['Tina Dash', 'Steve Ball', 'Tony Walker']
```

I need to replace all of the occurrences of the @name with items from the names list.  I have it mostly working but it is replacing the same name for each replacement.  Here's the function:

```
def findReplaceMentions():
   regex = r"@\w+\s\w+"
   for item in data:
      if '@' in item['comment']:
         commentString = str(item['comment'])
         commentString = re.sub(regex, '@'+names.pop(0), commentString)
         item['comment'] = commentString
```

This is resulting in:

```
{'comment': 'I nominate @Tina Dash and @Tina Dash'}, {'comment': '@Steve Ball check out the Queen's Gambit'}
```

But I need:

```
{'comment': 'I nominate @Tina Dash and @Steve Ball'}, {'comment': '@Tony Walker check out the Queen's Gambit'}
```

There could be any number of @'s in a single comment.  How do I substitute each occurrence of @name with a unique item from the list of names?

Comment: Your logic is not clear. Why would \@Steve Ball become \@Tony Walker?

Comment: Is it guaranteed that the number of `@` symbols is `<= len(names)`?

Comment: Yes, there will always be more names than @'s in the comments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a function replacement so a new name is popped per replacement:

```py
commentString = re.sub(regex, lambda match: '@' + names.pop(0), commentString)
```

As a side note, you really should be popping from the end instead of the start, as popping from the start is very inefficient. If you want to maintain the order, then first reverse the list before popping from the end.

Comment: Awesome, I didn't realize you could do function replacement in re.sub.  This works perfectly, thank you.  And thanks for the note on popping from the end, order doesn't matter in this case so I will modify, appreciate it.